# More than 5 mix/principled shaders turns material pink in material preview but not in rendered preview? No missing textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, texture-painting

I'm doing a 3D map with a single material only using masks to change between terrain types, but once I add more than 5 mix/principled shaders the material turns pink, this issue just happens in the material preview window, not in the rendered preview.

**Like so:**
[image: Like so]

**And as you can see it is not a missing texture issue either since it previews just fine if done separately.**
[image: And as you can see it is not a missing texture issue either]
[image: And as you can see it is not a missing texture issue either]

I need to fix this otherwise I can't paint on the masks, so if anyone can shed light on the situation I would be grateful, thanks!

I couldn't make the file size lower than 30mb since there are a lot of textures, I hope a google drive link is acceptable? [File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18JMAkQE5WFRgaSp1zv1hVcjSu1XXXVxI)

Comment: What are your system specs? Are you using CPU or GPU for render?

Comment: I'm using a GPU for rendering.  

My specs are:  
CPU: Ryzen 7 1700  
GPU: GTX 1070  
RAM: 2x8gb 3000Mhz  
OS: Windows 10 64bit

Comment: Are there any Principled BSDF shaders that are not needed and can be replaced with Diffuse BSDF?

Comment: Yeah, actually they can all be replaced with Diffuse shaders, however, I replaced a couple of them but the issue still persists, I'm gonna replace all of them and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed all the Principled BSDF shaders to simple Diffuse BSDF shaders, like [Craig](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/12662/craig-d-jones) suggested and it worked! Don't know the exact reason why it worked but I guess the Principled BSDF is too complex for putting a bunch of them in a single material. Anyway thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 0):

yes I get this same error with just 2 BSDF Principle Shaders. It's not tied to 3.0 or 2.93 or 2.91, it happens in all of them. Choosing CPU over GPU doesn't fix it either.

The only thing that did work was removing one of my BSDF Principle Shaders, and replacing it with a Diffuse Shader. That left me with just a single Principle Shader, so it appears you don't need to switch them all out. It seems just the one will always work. Just stay away from using a second one, or heaven forbid, 5 of them. The problem is worse when using Procedural methods for textures. There must be a lot of calculation going on we know very little about.